# angular.element.scope() is undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to add a controller in a new html content that will be added dynamically to an existing dom, but my scope is undefined. What is the best way of doing it? I'm new in Angular.

Sorry, here is my code:

```
var angularScript = document.createElement('script');
angularScript.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
angularScript.setAttribute('src','https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js');
document.head.appendChild(angularScript);

jQuery('body').append("<section id='custFA'><div id='getTable' data-ng-app='custom' data-ng-controller='customController'  style='overflow-y: auto !important;position:absolute; width: 300px; height: 200px; top:100px; left: 200px;'><button id='runCust' data-ng-click='codeRun()' style='top: 57px; left: 120px;'>Run</button></div></section>");

I'm inserting module and controller scripts as well, and the code in it:
Module:
setTimeout(function angularDefined(){
    if(angular){
        window.app = angular.module("custom",[]);
        console.log("angular");
    }
    else{
        setTimeout(angularDefined,1000);
    }
},1000);

controller:
function appDefined(){
    if(window.app){
        window.defined=true;
        console.log("appDefined");
        app.controller('customController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

            $scope.codeRun=function(){

                console.log("check");

            }

        }]);

    }
    else{
        setTimeout(appDefined,1000);

    }
};

appDefined();
```

Thanks

Comment: put some code, then we can help, you've basically described a very broad scenario

Comment: We really need a lot more information about what you are trying to do here, with the code you are using.

Comment: what is going on here? you are using jquery to dynamically create dynamic angular content? Why would you ever need to do this?

Comment: There is no angular on the page( it's not my page) but I want to build something with angular because I want to learn it and to check if it's possible to create it with angular. I know how to do it with jQuery

Comment: well what you are trying to do doesn't really make sense, but if you have absolutely no other way of including Angular, you'll have to bootstrap it manually rather than use ng-app.  Check the documentation on bootstrapping. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#!/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a controller first..per the docs:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

In your html: Let your view know which controller to use. Inside of that div you will have access to any variables on $scope

```
<div ng-controller="GreetingController">
   {{ greeting }}
</div>
```